# How do I run selenium after serving create react app application?

Tags: selenium, react-native, gruntjs, create-react-app

I am trying to make some e2e tests with selenium over my Create React App application.
The problem is that before selenium can even run, I must run the react application itself (using for example `npm start`).
The problem: serving the app will stay in 'watch' mode in any autumation process I am trying to build.

Is it possible to run a create react app, and only after that selenium? (using grunt, npm or whatever?)

The current flow:

1. Run react development server with grunt (using `npm start`)
2. Run selenium

Is there a way to make them work one after the other?

grunfile:

require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    const API = process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH + ':' + process.env.REACT_APP_API_PORT + '/api';
    const DEV_PORT = 3001;

```
grunt.initConfig({
    http: {
        prepare_e2e_tests: {
            options: {
                url: API + '/prepare_e2e_tests'
            }
        }
    },
    exec: {
        start_dev_server: {
            cmd: 'REACT_APP_IS_TESTING=true PORT=' + DEV_PORT + ' npm start'
        },
        e2e: {
            cmd: 'DEV_SERVER_PORT=3001 npm run e2e'
        }
    },
    concurrent: {
        test: {
            tasks: ['http:prepare_e2e_tests','exec:start_dev_server','exec:e2e'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('run_e2e', function() {
    console.log('running e2e tests');
    grutn.task.run('exec:e2e')
});

grunt.registerTask('prepare_server', function() {
    console.log('preparing e2e tests on server:');
    grunt.task.run('http:prepare_e2e_tests');
});

grunt.registerTask('setup_dev_server', function() {
    console.log('running development server on port ' + DEV_PORT);
    grunt.task.run('exec:start_dev_server');

});

grunt.registerTask('test', 'run e2e tests', ['concurrent:test']);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-http');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');

grunt.registerTask('default', []);
```

};

Thanks!

Comment: How are you executing the test as of now? Your question needs a lot more details for someone to comment

Comment: hopefully now it will be more clear

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/litek/gulp-bg